# What is the problem with my merge sort code?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Just writing some basic mergeSort code and I can't figure out if there is something wrong with my logic. To me it should work fine.

So, ideally it should print out elements in sorted order: 1 2 8 11 17 19 25 50.

But the output displayed is: 8 2 11 1 17 19 25 50

I am not getting what's wrong with this code. Am I going wrong with the logic?

If somebody can help me out it would be great.
Sorry if this is a very silly question to ask here.

```
public class MergeSort
{
    static final int arr[] = {8, 2, 19, 25, 11, 1, 17, 50};
    static int sorted[] = new int[arr.length];
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        mergeSort(0, arr.length - 1);
        
        display();
    }
    
    static void display()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<sorted.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(sorted[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    
    static void mergeSort(int first, int last)
    {
        if(first < last)
        {
            int mid = (first + last)/2;
            mergeSort(first, mid);
            mergeSort(mid + 1, last);
            merge(first, mid, last);
        }
    }
    
    static void merge(int first, int mid, int last)
    {
        int ansIndex = 0;
        int index1 = first;
        int index2 = mid + 1;
        
        while(index1 <= mid && index2 <= last)
            if(arr[index1] < arr[index2])
            {
                sorted[ansIndex] = arr[index1];
                index1++;
                ansIndex++;
            }
            else if(arr[index2] < arr[index1])
            {
                sorted[ansIndex] = arr[index2];
                index2++;
                ansIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                sorted[ansIndex] = arr[index1];
                index1++; index2++; ansIndex++;
            }
        
        if(index1 <= mid)
            while(index1 <= mid)
            {
                sorted[ansIndex] = arr[index1];
                ansIndex++; index1++;
            }
        else if(index2 <= last)
            while(index2 <= last)
            {
                sorted[ansIndex] = arr[index2];
                index2++; ansIndex++;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the result is wrong, then yes, there is a logical problem with your merge sort code. Did you really need to ask us that, to know that?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Comment: *"Am I going wrong with the logic?"* Yes. Anything else you wanted to know?

Comment: There are lots of descriptions online for merge/sort algorithm. Have you walked through your design to see how well it aligns?

Comment: I would also recommend to use `{}` for all `if`- and `while`-statements in order to increase readability and traceability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is using the same arrays `arr` and `sorted` at every step without copying data.

The simplest correction is copying range of range `0..ansIndex` from `sorted` to the range `first..last` of `arr` in the end of `merge`

Also `display` should show `arr`  (`sorted` is just temporary buffer)